# Serialize Tuple<string, byte> without returning m_Item1, m_Item2

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I'm developing an ASP.NET Web Api application with .NET Framework 4.6.1, C# and JSON.Net.

I'm getting problems returning a list of Tuple. I get this json:

```
[
  {
    "m_Item1": "88962730000000378995",
    "m_Item2": 2
  }
]
```

I'm using this code:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = null;
List<Tuple<string, byte>> exCodes = null;

[ ... ]

response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, exCodes);
```

But I want to get this:

```
[  {
    "Item1": "88962730000000378995",
    "Item2": 2
  }
]
```

To get that code I have to use this code:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = null;
List<Tuple<string, byte>> exCodes = null;

[ ... ]

var j = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
j.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver();

response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, exCodes);
```

But I'm not sure if this code `j.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver();` will affect the rest of the service.

Is there another way to get the Json that I want without using `new DefaultContractResolver();`?

Comment: I got `[{"Item1":"88962730000000378995","Item2":2}]` on my machine. What version of .NET ?

Comment: What about using an anonymous object with `Item1` and `Item2` as properties instead of using `Tuple`?

Comment: @GeorgeChond How can I use an anonymous object?

Comment: @user3185569 It's at the first paragraph of my question: 4.6.1.

Comment: @GeorgeChond I was just writing the same method :)

Comment: Perhaps late to the party, but does `response = Request.CreateResponse(Json(exCodes))` the trick?

Answer (score 2):

You can create an anonymous object:

```
var anon = exCodes.Select(x => new { x.Item1, x.Item2 });

response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, anon);
```